# Cytoscape with Angular and Typesript error TS2305: Module has no default export

Tags: angular, typescript, types, cytoscape.js

I have an app in Angular and I try to use Cytoscape. I install Cystoscape and Types/cytoscape with npm to use, but when I import a take a error.
I start a new project just for test before implement on my app.

My app.module

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { GraphComponent } from './graphCytoscape/graph.component';
import cytoscape = require('cytoscape');


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    GraphComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
  ],
  exports: [],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

My component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import cytoscape from 'cytoscape';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-graph',
    templateUrl: 'graph.component.html'
})

export class GraphComponent implements OnInit {
    cy;
    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.cy = cytoscape({
             container: document.getElementById('cy'),
             elements: [
                { data: { id: 'a' } },
                { data: { id: 'b' } },
                { data: {
                    id: {
                        id: 'ab',
                        source: 'a',
                        target: 'b',
                    }
                }
            },
        ]
    });
   }
 }
```

And this is my error:

```
ERROR in src/app/graphCytoscape/graph.component.ts(2,8): error TS2305: Module '"C:/Users/hudson.joubert/Documents/projects/cytoscopeJS/node_modules/@types/cytoscape/index"' has no
```

default export.

but I enter on node_modules and is there, but I dont know how to resolve this.

Comment: "has no" what ? your error message is not complete

Answer (score 0):

For this error:

> ERROR in src/app/graphCytoscape/graph.component.ts(2,8): error TS2305: Module '"C:/Users/hudson.joubert/Documents/projects/cytoscopeJS/node_modules/@types/cytoscape/index"' ...

You need  Install the type declaration file: `npm import @types/cytoscape`